# 0xC0000005 - Access violation (Each time from a different dll)

Tags: visual-c++, dll, access-violation

I have been given a task to debug a C++ project. I have not written a single line of code in this project!!

This project executes for about 5 minutes without problem. Then it ends with an exception
"Unhandled exception at  (some .dll name) in EITos.exe:
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location "

Now every time I execute the program. The error is from a different dll. Sometimes it is a dll created by other programmers, sometimes it is related to QT. So I don't think this is a code problem. Is there any project setting that would affect this?

I am asking some general tips and hints as to how to debug this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A common problem when working with DLLs is allocating memory in a DLL and de-allocating it somewhere else (in another DLL or in the main executable). I think your problem might come from something like that.

One quick solution is to use the `/MD` compiler flag for all the projects you are using. This option specifies that the run-time library should be linked dynamically to your executables, so that the same allocators/de-allocators are used between the dlls. You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Also, take care about this:

> Do not mix static and dynamic versions of the run-time libraries. Having more than one copy of the run-time libraries in a process can cause problems, because static data in one copy is not shared with the other copy. The linker prevents you from linking with both static and dynamic versions within one .exe file, but you can still end up with two (or more) copies of the run-time libraries. For example, a dynamic-link library linked with the static (non-DLL) versions of the run-time libraries can cause problems when used with an .exe file that was linked with the dynamic (DLL) version of the run-time libraries. (You should also avoid mixing the debug and non-debug versions of the libraries in one process.)

Another way would be not to allocate memory in one dll and de-allocate it in another. So you can check the code, eventually re-write it. But this is more time consuming.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But it did not seem to help. I am now checking through this huge code right now.